# Create new s3 client instances in Spark tasks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have the following method in my spark application:

```
private def downloadChunk(sitemChunk : DataChunk) : String = {

    val s3Client = new AmazonS3Client()
    val fileName = s3Client.getObject(....)

    fileName
}
```

which is basically download files from S3 when it gets executed in Spark tasks,

```
val mydata = sc.parallelize(listOfChunks)
mydata.map(x => downloadChunk(x)).collect
```

I am afraid that I am making new instance of s3Client for each task, is there a better way?

Comment: Is makeing new client instance the most resource-intensive operation? What other option could you have if downloadChunk could run on different executors (i.e. cluster nodes)?

Comment: s3Client already has some connection pool itself to re-use the http connection, re-using the same instance would be enough but not sure if this will work in executors..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a new client on every mapper - they are executed in different jvms (and, possibly, on different nodes), so reusing the same client isn't an option.

What you can do is use `.mapPartitions`:

```
  myData.mapPartitions { part =>
     val client = new AmazonS3Client
     part.flatMap { chunk => client.getObject(...) }
  }
```

This way, you are creating the client once per mapper, rather than for every single element of the rdd.